# Loading dynamic controls using angular js in asp.net MVC5 application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a project that is going to be built using MVC5, angularJS and bootstrap.

I have a dropdown called expense type. On selecting a value from the dropdown I have few other controls to be loaded in my view.

Some of these controls are dependent on the value that is selected in the expense type dropdown and some controls are fixed already. Based on the value selected my controller will query the database and get the data required for the dynamic controls to be loaded in my view. But how do I render it in my view using angularjs?. The number of controls and the type of controls is totally dependent on the dropdown value selected. The type of the control and values are coming from the database.

Please suggest how I can proceed.

Comment: Did you try smething? have you some code to show?

Comment: No. I have'nt tried anything for now. I am new to angular JS.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of controllers definition that will be bound in your view.

for example in your controller :

```
var WorkSpaceAdd = function (controller, name, url) {
    var id = $scope.workspaces.length + 1;
    $scope.workspaces.push({
        url: url,
        controller: controller,
        id: id,
        name: name,
        active: true,
        disabled: false
    });
};
```

and in your view

```
<div ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
     active="workspace.active" disabled="workspace.disabled">
    <div ng-init="workspace=workspace" ng-include="workspace.url">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am new to angular JS and do not understand how this works. Can you please give me an answer that is specific to my problem?